# Storm Hbase Configuration not found

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-storm

So I have set up a storm spout coming from kafka and a bolt writing to the HDFS. This all works fine. I now want to add a new bolt which write to Hbase. For some reason, my application is not picking up the hbase configuration stuff and I get the following error:

```
            java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HBase configuration not found using key 'null'
                    at org.apache.storm.hbase.bolt.AbstractHBaseBolt.prepare(AbstractHBaseBolt.java:58) ~[storm-hbase-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5697$fn__5710.invoke(executor.clj:732) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__452.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
            2015-04-16 02:05:44 b.s.d.executor [ERROR]
            java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HBase configuration not found using key 'null'
                    at org.apache.storm.hbase.bolt.AbstractHBaseBolt.prepare(AbstractHBaseBolt.java:58) ~[storm-hbase-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5697$fn__5710.invoke(executor.clj:732) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__452.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
            2015-04-16 02:05:44 o.a.h.u.NativeCodeLoader [WARN] Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
            2015-04-16 02:05:44 b.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Worker died")
            java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
                    at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:322) [storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
                    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__6109$fn__6110.invoke(worker.clj:495) [storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__5530$fn__5531.invoke(executor.clj:245) [storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__452.invoke(util.clj:475) [storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
```

When I look at the code it shows the following block where the error is occuring:

```
           public void prepare(Map map, TopologyContext topologyContext, OutputCollector collector) {
                this.collector = collector;
                final Configuration hbConfig = HBaseConfiguration.create();

                Map<String, Object> conf = (Map<String, Object>)map.get(this.configKey);
                if(conf == null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("HBase configuration not found using key '" + this.configKey + "'");
                }
```

It looks like configKey isn't getting set anywhere so I tried to set it ion the HBaseBolt method as below:

```
    SimpleHBaseMapper mapper = new SimpleHBaseMapper() 
    .withRowKeyField("CustomerId")
    .withColumnFields(new Fields("CustomerId"))
    .withCounterFields(new Fields("Count"))
    .withColumnFamily("cf1");

    HBaseBolt hbase = new HBaseBolt("Customer", mapper).withConfigKey("/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml");        
    builder.setBolt("HBASE_BOLT", hbase, 1)
    .fieldsGrouping("stormspout", new Fields("CustomerId"));
```

Didn't seem to do anything though as I am still getting the same error....
Anyone have any suggestions?! It feels like its just not picking up my hbase-site.xml file but I'm not sure why not...

Answer (score 1):

After lots of work, I finally got this to work!!

In your topology createConfig method, add

```
    Map<String, String> HBConfig = Maps.newHashMap();
    HBConfig.put("hbase.rootdir","hdfs://<IP Address>:8020/hbase");
    conf.put("HBCONFIG",HBConfig);
```

When you instantiate HBaseBolt, do so using
.withConfigKey("HBCONFIG")

Comment: if you have a secured hbase cluster, do you know how to pass the credentials? @Colman

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up writing my own hbasebolt that implements IRichBolt. I then did an override on the prepare method and built the following configuration which seemed to solve my problem :-)

```
            Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
            conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "sandbox.hortonworks.com"); 
            conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
            conf.set("zookeeper.session.timeout", "1200000");
            conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.tickTime", "6000");
            conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");
            conf.set("hbase.coprocessor.region.classes", "com.xasecure.authorization.hbase.XaSecureAuthorizationCoprocessor");
            conf.set("hbase.coprocessor.master.classes", "com.xasecure.authorization.hbase.XaSecureAuthorizationCoprocessor");  

            admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
            table = new HTable(conf, _tableName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the configuration section name for your HBase settings in your configuration of topology:

```
 Config cfg = new Config();
 Map<String, String> HBConfig = Maps.newHashMap();
 HBConfig.put(somekey,somevalue);
 cfg.put("HBCONFIG",HBConfig);
 StormSubmitter.submitTopology(TOPOLOGY_NAME, cfg, builder.createTopology());
```

Then in your HBase bolt configuration set this key as a bolt configuration key:

```
  HBaseBolt bolt = new HBaseBolt("table_name", mapper).withConfigKey("HBCONFIG");
```